# Connection to http://10.0.3.2:8081 refused

Tags: android, mysql, logcat, genymotion

I am trying to provide a connection between my **android application** and **MySQL database**. I am using **Genymotion emulator**. When I run the application the page is displayed properly on the emulator but once I press submit button nothing happen and the data is not reflected in the database.

I have referred following solutions but all in vain:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFE1M.png) [Connection to https://xxx.x.x.x refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317549/connection-to-https-xxx-x-x-x-refused)

[2] [Connection to database mySQL failed from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789621/connection-to-database-mysql-failed-from-android)

Logcat for the same is as follows:

[image: Error Logcat image]

Will be grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: `the page is displayed properly on the emulator `. You mean displayed properly by your app on the emulator. In what of your app? What kind of submit button are you talking about?

Comment: Are you trying to connect directly to the database from your Android app?  That's generally a bad idea anyway.

Comment: I am using JSP as intermediate. **Android-JSP-MySQL**, because android cannot communicate directly to MySQL. There are ways to do that using PHP or JSON but I chose to do it using JSP.